# has_many through and values on the join table with Cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

I can't seem to get my forms working correctly despite following many guides, tutorials and examples.

I have a model `location.rb`:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_gateways
  has_many :gateways, through: :location_gateways, dependent: :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location_gateways, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

The joining table has an attribute `bearing` and the model (`location_gateway.rb`):

```
class LocationGateway < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :gateway, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gateway, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

The form looks like this (`location/new.html.erb`):

```
<div id="locations-form">
        <%= form_with model: @location do |f| %>
          <%= render 'partials/locations_form', f:f %>

          <div class="form-group" id="location_gateways"> 
            <b><%= 'Add gateway', f, :location_gateways, partial: 'partials/gateway_fields'%></b>
          </div>

          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit nil, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

Nested form (`_gateway_fields.html.erb`)

```
<div class="nested-fields" >
    <div class="row">
        <%= f.fields_for :gateways do |g| %>
          <div class="col-md-4" >
            <%= g.text_field :longitude, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= g.text_field :latitude, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="col-md-2" >
          <%= f.text_field :bearing, class: 'form-control gateway-longitude' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <%= link_to_remove_association  raw(icon_trash), f  %>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to add `latitude` and `longitude` for the `gateway` association while adding the `bearing` to the joining table `location_gateway`.

However, my params comes out like this:

```
{ ... "location_gateways_attributes"=>
  {"1593162006925"=>
    {
       "gateways"=>{"longitude"=>"12.3456", "latitude"=>"13.4567"}, 
       "bearing"=>"123", "_destroy"=>"false"
    }
  }
}
```

Why does it become `gateways` rather than `gateways_attributes`?

Comment: Have you added //= require in your application.js file

Comment: Why does it become gateways rather than gateways_attributes? <<<<< its a naming convention used for nested attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I initially misread your code: I thought you created the gateways directly on the `has_many :gateways` association. In which case you would be missing the
`accepts_nested_attributes_for :gateways` on `Location` level.

But after your feedback and looking a bit closer I noticed you correctly followed the associations (you have a double/nested `fields_for`), so you have the correct `accepts_nested_attributes_for` declared in your models.

However.... in your nested model you write `fields_for :gateways` --- BUT since you are now nested in a `LocationGateway` that association does not exist there, instead you have to write `f.fields_for :gateway` and then it will all work as expected.

So what I said before still stands: That is also why the parameter is called `gateways` instead of `gateways_attributes`: that is indicative of a missing `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Or more precisely in this case: using the wrong association.

[EDIT] Now we have an `link_to_add_association 'Add gateway', f, :location_gateways, partial: 'partials/gateway_fields'` which creates a new `LocationGateway`, but *not* the nested `Gateway`. So now you have two options:

- add a second `link_to_add_association` for `:gateway` but this would be confusing for the user
- directly initialise the `LocationGateway` to include the `Gateway`

and for this last option we can use the cocoon option `wrap_object` as follows:

```
link_to_add_association 'Add gateway', f, :location_gateways, 
   partial: 'partials/gateway_fields',
   wrap_object: Proc.new {|x| x.build_gateway; x }
```

Comment: I really appreciate getting input from the cocoon creator, thanks!
However, adding the accepts_nested_attributes_for :gateways to the location model changes nothing. Params look the same

Comment: Ha right: I initially misread your question/code, confused by the `fields_for :gateways`. Short answer: you have to write `f.fields_for :gateway` since in the `LocationGateway` that is the only association that exists.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and updated response!
Trying to add `f.fields_for :gateway` I get nothing in the form. Now only the bearing are shown when adding a Gateway (latitude and longitude are not visible - nor are they in the page code)

Comment: However, the fields are visible in edit. So seems to be related to the gateway not being initialised. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, normally one has to add a `link_to_add_association` for each dynamically created object. Now we only create the `location_gateway`, and not the nested `gateway` (so that is why I assumed you created the object directly on the `gateways` association. But, this is easily solved by using a wrap-object initialiser. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is in no way a clean answer but I got it working if I changed the fields for argument to this (note the non-pluralized version of gateway):

```
<%= f.fields_for :gateway_attributes do |g| %>
```

With this "solution", no `accepts_nested_attributes_for :gateways` is needed on the Location model.